# Grails dependencies neo4j

Tags: grails, maven-2, ivy, dependency-management, neo4j

I'm suffering from grails dependencies with only pom.xml in the jar files at the moment. Basically, I'm trying to use grails dependencies to include neo4j which the main file only contain pom.xml http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22neo4j%22.

This is my BuildConfig.groovy

```
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
//grails.project.war.file = "target/${appName}-${appVersion}.war"
grails.project.war.file = "target/ROOT.war"
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    // inherit Grails' default dependencies
    inherits("global") {
        // uncomment to disable ehcache
        // excludes 'ehcache'
    }
    log "warn" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
    repositories {
        grailsPlugins()
        grailsHome()
        grailsCentral()

        // uncomment the below to enable remote dependency resolution
        // from public Maven repositories
        mavenLocal()
//        mavenCentral()
//        mavenRepo "http://m2.neo4j.org/snapshots/"
//        flatDir name:'neo4j', dirs:'/lib/neo4j'
        //mavenRepo "http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org"
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
        //mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"

        /*
         * Configure our resolver.
         */
//        def libResolver = new org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.URLResolver()
//        ['libraries', 'builds'].each {
//            libResolver.addArtifactPattern(
//                    "/Users/ncharass/.ivy/cache/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]")
//
//        }
//        libResolver.name = "my-repository"
//        libResolver.settings = ivySettings
//        resolver libResolver
    }
    dependencies {
        // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes eg.
        compile 'org.neo4j:neo4j:1.4.1'
        // runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.13'
    }
}
```

It seems to download all the jar files successfully, but those jars only contain pom.xml which it seems that Gradle or Ivy doesn't pick up any pom.xml for any references, so I got complication errors.

I tried almost everything but it doesn't seem to work. Also, the lib that I download from neo4j website also only contains pom.xml.

Please help! :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone already proposed the following on the [neo4j mailing list](http://lists.neo4j.org/pipermail/user/2011-August/011129.html):

```
repositories {
    grailsPlugins()
    grailsHome()
    grailsCentral()

    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()

    flatDir name:'neo4j', dirs:'/${PATH}/lib/neo4j'

}
dependencies {

    compile 'org.neo4j:neo4j-kernel:1.4.1'
    compile 'org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher:1.4.1'
    compile 'org.neo4j:neo4j-graph-algo:1.4.1'
    compile 'org.neo4j:neo4j-graph-matching:1.4.1'
    compile 'org.neo4j:neo4j-jmx:1.4.1'
    compile 'org.neo4j:neo4j-lucene-index:1.4.1'
    compile 'org.neo4j:neo4j-shell:1.4.1'
    compile 'org.neo4j:neo4j-udc:1.4.1'
    compile 'org.neo4j:lucene-core:3.1.0'
    compile 'org.neo4j:scala-library:2.9.0-1'
    compile 'org.neo4j:server-api:1.4.1'

}
```

Answer (score 0):

or just use

```
compile 'org.neo4j:neo4j-community:1.4.1'
```

in the dependencies section.